# Anything I could cite to make my apartment complex more flexible regarding their inspections in Texas?

Tags: real-estate, tenant

So my apartment complex likes to do these pretend inspections which means they are about to sell the property again and they act like these are routine legal inspections of your HVAC unit, but again, I think its just because they want to sell the place again.

My wife will be home alone with my child and she does not feel comfortable being alone with a couple men in our home.

Is there any type of pushback that I could cite legally to have management have to be flexible and do this at a time that is more comfortable for my family and I?

This is occurring in the state of Texas by the way.

I don't believe there is documentation that I ever signed agreeing to this, in fact, not even a conversation, because again, I believe they only do this when they are about to sell the property to another management group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right to "quiet enjoyment" in the state of Texas. That means that you should be left alone to enjoy your rental property, unless there is a valid reason to disturb you.https://www.texasattorneygeneral.gov/consumer-protection/home-real-estate-and-travel/renters-rights

There isn't a set in stone limit to the inspections, but some rental agreements require that inspections be announced a certain amount of time before they occur, so check yours if you haven't.

You could go to court and ask a judge to limit the number or frequency of inspections, but you would have to show that there an abnormal amount. Also, if it really is because they are selling, the potential buyer has the right to look at the property.

Maybe you could explain that you would like to be there when they occur and try to schedule the inspections for when you, yourself, are home.